# cast an interval to a timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where

```
      date               | interval
 juin 1, 2022, 12:00 AM  | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 58.963179 secs
 juin 2, 2022, 12:00 AM  | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 2 mins 34.083955 secs
 juin 3, 2022, 12:00 AM  | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 2 mins 51.152488 secs
```

etc...

I want to cast the interval to have a timestamp. I am in postresql

```
 SELECT 
 DATE_TRUNC('day', "order_date") as date_authorised,
 avg("difference") AS "avg_time"
 FROM "test"
 where  date_trunc('day',order_date)<date_trunc('day',current_date)
 GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', "order_date")
```

thats my code

Answer (score 3):

Saeeds answer is correct. You cannot convert an interval to a timestamp, since they are two separate things. You can however add an interval to a timestamp to receive a new timestamp. This can be done in Postgres with the '+' operator.

Example SQL code:

```
select '2022-07-12 12:00:00'::timestamp + '1 days'::interval;

      ?column?
---------------------
 2022-07-13 12:00:00
```

Notice the new timestamp that now has one day added.

Answer (score 1):

date + interval → timestamp

Add an interval to a date

date '2001-09-28' + interval '1 hour' → 2001-09-28 01:00:00

SELECT  to_timestamp('2020-01-10 08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')::timestamp without time zone
at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta'
-
to_timestamp('2020-01-10 08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')::timestamp without time zone
at time zone 'Etc/UTC'